# Laravel ignoring case-sensitivity in relationships when running test-suites

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a relationship defined as :

```
  public function contract(){
    return $this->belongsTo(contract::class);
  }
```

When I call this relationship in test suites. I get no error. It ignores the case-sensitivity and successfully loads the class `Contract` instead of `contract` which doesn't exist.

But the same relationship when called through normal client call, it throws and error `Class 'App\Models\contract' not found` .

Why laravel is not throwing any error when this relationship is called through test-suites.Can we disable this behaviour?

Comment: But why are you referencing a class that does not exist?

Comment: @Hamelraj. thats a useless thing you are saying. I am saying above its just the 'contract' vs 'Contract'

Comment: @Jerodev. It is not about why I am doing. It is about why it is happening. I perform Test Driven Development. Hope you can further things why I asked this.

Comment: I don't know why this happens, but this is something to do with the autoloader from composer, Laravel has nothing to do with this.

Comment: But I am performing this on the same system. It should be an issue then both side. Since laravel uses drivers for rest-API call to the server on test cases, could it be it is somehow ignoring the case-sensitivity there?

Comment: Windows systems are not case sensitive whereas UNIX systems are. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Nope I told I am getting this issue on the same machine. ( Linux )